# Telerik mvc multiple controls only renders one or the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

MVC 3 Telerik 2012.1.214
Hello,

I have been at this for some time and it is really beating me up. I have been through countless changes and tried many different articles, documents, and suggestions. My problem is simple. I want to have two Telerik controls on the page. Only one or the other will render. I did try one variation that resulted in neither rendering.

This seems so straight forward which is adding to my frustration.

in the cshtml razor code I have this:

```
@{
   Html.Telerik().Window()
   .Name("Window")
   ....etc....
  }

some html ....then

@{  Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip")
    .Items(tabstrip =>...)
     etc...
    .Render();
  }
```

In this scenario the TabString will render. If I put render on both the first will render. if I use @() instead @{} neither will render.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question more. You are saying - If you keep both window and tabstrip inside @{} and put .Render() on both only the window will render. - If you put both window and tabstrip inside @() instead of @{} neither will render. Have I understood you correctly?  As a side note @() will render what's inside and @{} is there to execute some code.    http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: If window & tab are in @{} and render is on both the first...which is window in this case..will render. I tried...but may very well have done it wrong...@() with neither having render and in that case neither did render. When I did the @() I tried it as @(window) and a seperate @(tab). I think I also tried @(window, tab) and didn't have any luck...again I am sure the problem is my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have said I don't think you are doing anything wrong with respect to using Telerik controls. However please try the following;

1. Remove all the middle 'html' in between the 2 controls and try
2. Render the page in Chrome and check the console for any rendering issues
3. Check the rendered Html to verify that the 2 controls are indeed not rendered. May be they are rendered but you don't see them in the browser for some reason

I have tried rendering a page similar to yours and both methods @() and @{} did work for me and here's the code

```
@{
Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("Window1")
    .Content("<h1>Window1</h1>")
    .Draggable(true)
    .Render();
} 

<span>Here is the middle html</span>

@{
Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip1")
    .Items(items =>
               {
                   items.Add().Content("<h1>Tab 1</h1>").Text("Tab 1").Visible(true);
                   items.Add().Content("<h1>Tab 2</h1>").Text("Tab 2");
                   items.Add().Content("<h1>Tab 3</h1>").Text("Tab 3");
               })
    .Render();
}
```

Here's the @() way;

```
@(
Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("Window2")
    .Content("<h1>Window2</h1>")
    .Draggable(true)
)

<span>Here is the middle html</span>

@(
Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
    .Name("TabStrip2")
    .Items(items =>
               {
                   items.Add().Content("<h1>Tab 1</h1>").Text("Tab 1").Visible(true);
                   items.Add().Content("<h1>Tab 2</h1>").Text("Tab 2");
                   items.Add().Content("<h1>Tab 3</h1>").Text("Tab 3");
               })
)
```

Answer (score -1):

That's strange, because I'm not having this kind of problem...
Can you put the entire code that you use in your view ?
And did you check if you had any JS errors ?

Comment: this is not an answer. if you have any question, you should ask him in comment. Stackoverflow is not a forum, it is a Q/A system.

Comment: I would comment if I could, but I haven't got enough reputation to do it (50 needed). How can I ask for more details to help him if I can't comment (I'm just asking here, no offense)

Comment: I think currently you can't do this! You can ask it as a question too! :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. :( Are you talking about creating a new Stackoverflow question so that I can get more detail about his question ?